# Proxychains – ssh working but not scp on macOS Sierra

Tags: ssh, scp, macos-sierra

I use `proxychains4` in macOS Sierra and have an issue with `scp`.

For SSH I counter the pb by copying the `ssh` from `/usr/bin` to `/User/mylaptop`, then use this to ssh:

```
proxychains4 /users/mylaptop/ssh user@host
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /opt/local/lib/libproxychains4.dylib
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
[proxychains] Strict chain .........
```

and then I can connect to my host. **But `scp` won't work.**

I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) ships with a new security feature called SIP
  that prevents hooking of system apps.
  workarounds are to partially disable SIP by issuing

```
    csrutil enable --without debug
```

in recovery mode,
  or to copy the system binary into the home directory and run it from there.
  see github issue #78 for details.
https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/issues/78